# Terminal "open" any image results in "Preview quit unexpectedly"

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, preview

Whenever I hit `open blah.png` (any image type) in my terminal, I get a message "Preview quit unexpectedly" from Mac OS X. The solution is to just open the folder in Finder using `open .`, navigating to the file and opening it from there. Preview seems to work fine then. However, this is annoying.

Any ideas why I can't `open` images from the terminal?

My OS X version is 10.10.5 (14F1808). By the way, when I hit ``open receptor.png'' (where receptor.png is the filename), the terminal now also says: "LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/asdf/receptor.png." I don't know why I didn't notice that before.

Comment: In Terminal, can you test the following with an image file that's known to crash Preview when using `open filename`, for testing purposes use instead, `open -a Preview filename`. Does it still crash Preview?

Comment: hey, thanks for the response --- yeah unfortunately I get exactly the same error message ...

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? What size are the files you are trying to open?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS version 10.10.5 (14F1808) . The size of the files varies. But one test png for example is 149K. I added a little more information to the question

Comment: are giving the direct file path?

Comment: No, I'm usually giving the relative path, but I just tested with the absolute path and it didn't help either

Comment: What happens if you open the file in Preview by double clicking on it?

Comment: @Hinton try `chmod +x` on the file, anything then?

Comment: From Preview, all files open fine. My current workaround is "open ." and the double-clicking the file ... which is slower than just saying "open file.png". @ruddfawcett, chmod +x doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: I have been attempting to replicate the problem and thus far, I have only been able to get it to fail once.  However, since I issued the command `open -n foo.bar` it never did it again.  Try using `-n` to force Preview to start a new instance and report back.

Comment: Opening with `open -n receptor.png` results in the same error, sorry

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of cache-type files that will clear most issues with Preview, if you delete them.  I've also heard of several similar issues arising out of **ACL** (Access Control Lists) being out of sync across your system.

First reset the ACL for your account, like this.  Use [this](https://www.macissues.com/2014/04/11/how-to-fix-home-folder-permissions-in-os-x/) as a more detailed reference as needed.  *Just to remedy Preview.app  issues, You probably do not need to remove all the permissions on your account,* so ignore their first step where they are using `chmod` in the terminal.  I would reccomend:

- Restart the computer, and on the chime, hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- At the top of the screen, chose "Utilities" --> "Terminal"
- In Terminal type `resetpassword` (you can also use one of your old passwords)
- Click on "Save"
- Press "Reset" (just below), which resets the Access Control Lists.

Now login to your computer, and remove the Preview cache & preference files.  I've used [this link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7180943?start=0&tstart=0) as a reference to confirm the locations:

Open **Finder** and then navigate to your User Library by holding <kbd>alt</kbd>, and chosing from the "Go" menu at the top, "Library."  If you're confident with the terminal, of course you can also delete them that way.  For example:  `cd $HOME/Library/` then `rm -Rf [each file below]`.  Don't use terminal if you are not used to it!

clear the various caches and temporary files related to **Preview** by deleting:

- 'Containers/com.apple.Preview'
- 'Containers/com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper'
- 'Preferences/com.apple.Preview.LSSharedFileList.plist'
- 'Preferences/com.apple.Preview.SandboxedPersistentURLs.LSSharedFileList.plist'
- 'Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState'

***DO NOT OPEN PREVIEW BEFORE LOGGING OUT WITHOUT PERSISTANCE AND RESTARTING.***

Now, do a complete shutdown of your system, bring it back up.  This fixes most non-critical issues with Preview.app.  Make sure that when you shutdown, the box is **not** checked "remember my open programs."

If these steps do not solve the problem, assuming you are not running cracked or unauthorized software, you should reinstall OSX or seek professional help from an Authorized Apple Support center, because the problem is quite unusual and could be serious.

Comment: Wow. I have no idea if this is going to work or not but I'll definitely try ASAP. Thanks so much

Comment: I used dtrace/dtruss to diagnose and fix my crashing Preview without rebooting, see my answer at https://StackOverflow.com/a/51264006/3008405